# How to render the entity map of type LINK of draft js in my react component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, rich-text-editor, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I have this data in my redux store which I want to render in my react component .

```
{
"entityMap":{
      "0":{
           "type":"LINK",
           "mutability":"MUTABLE",
           "data":{"url":"www.google.co.in"}
          }
       },
"blocks":[
      {
        "key":"9k5h7",
         "text":"this is the link", 
         "type":"unstyled",
         "depth":0,
         "inlineStyleRanges":[],
         "entityRanges":[
             {
                "offset":12,
                "length":4,
                "key":0
             }
          ],
         "data":{}
       }
   ]
}
```

I succesfully managed to create a link type with  draft editor and was able to store it in  database and while rendering it I am getting the entire text except for the link . I have this link information in my redux i.e the "entity map" and also the "entityRanges" inside "blocks" which tells on which offset the link starts and what is the length . for eg, here in my case it is "link" in "this is the link" .

Here is the code which i used to render the above json from my redux :

```
render(){
     return(
            <div>

                {
                    var nn = abovejsonfromreduxstore;
                    var editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(nn)));
               return (        
                      <div>
                          <pre>
                              <Editor 
                                  editorState={editorState}
                                  readOnly 
                               />
                          </pre>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               }

        </div>

        );
```

}

How to modify this rendering method so that it renders the link entity too ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should specify [draft.js decorator](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-decorators.html#content) this way:

```
const decorator = new CompositeDecorator([
  {
    strategy: findLinkEntities,
    component: Link,
  },
]);
```

Pass the `findLinkEntities` function to `strategy` property and `Link` react component to `component` property:

```
function findLinkEntities(contentBlock, callback, contentState) {
  contentBlock.findEntityRanges(
    (character) => {
      const entityKey = character.getEntity();
      return (
        entityKey !== null &&
        contentState.getEntity(entityKey).getType() === 'LINK'
      );
    },
    callback
  );
}


const Link = (props) => {
  const {url} = props.contentState.getEntity(props.entityKey).getData();
  return (
    <a href={url}>
      {props.children}
    </a>
  );
};
```

After that pass this decorator to `createWithContent` method:

```
this.state = {
  editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(initialStateRaw), decorator)
};
```

Check working example in the hidden snippet below:

```js
const {Editor, CompositeDecorator, convertFromRaw, EditorState} = Draft;

const initialStateRaw = {
"entityMap":{
      "0":{
           "type":"LINK",
           "mutability":"MUTABLE",
           "data":{"url":"www.google.co.in"}
          }
       },
"blocks":[
      {
        "key":"9k5h7",
         "text":"this is the link", 
         "type":"unstyled",
         "depth":0,
         "inlineStyleRanges":[],
         "entityRanges":[
             {
                "offset":12,
                "length":4,
                "key":0
             }
          ],
         "data":{}
       }
   ]
};

function findLinkEntities(contentBlock, callback, contentState) {
  contentBlock.findEntityRanges(
    (character) => {
      const entityKey = character.getEntity();
      return (
        entityKey !== null &&
        contentState.getEntity(entityKey).getType() === 'LINK'
      );
    },
    callback
  );
}

const Link = (props) => {
  const {url} = props.contentState.getEntity(props.entityKey).getData();
  return (
    <a href={url}>
      {props.children}
    </a>
  );
};

class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    const decorator = new CompositeDecorator([
      {
        strategy: findLinkEntities,
        component: Link,
      },
    ]);

    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(initialStateRaw), decorator)
    };
  }
  
  _handleChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({ editorState });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-root">
        <Editor 
          placeholder="Type away :)"
          editorState={this.state.editorState}
          onChange={this._handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.getElementById('react-root'))
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container-root {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/draft-js/0.7.0/Draft.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/draft-js/0.10.0/Draft.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Comment: also you can add `className` to link, and then get that `className` in `entityMap[n].data`, which can be used as
`const {url, className} = props.contentState.getEntity(props.entityKey).getData();`